# What is $p'(1-x), p(x)=x$?

Tags: derivatives

Say if $p(x)=x $ and I want to find $p'(1-x)$ how do i go about it?. I would have thought it was $\frac{d}{d(1-x)}(x)$ but this doesn't give me the right answer.

Comment: Use chain rule.

Comment: In what manner?

Comment: Do you mean p'(1-x) or [p(1-x)]'

Comment: It's written as p'(1-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dP(x)}{dx}=1 \implies \frac{dP(y)}{dy}=1\\ \frac{dP(y)}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}=1 
\\ \frac{dP(y)}{dx}\cdot -1=1  \implies \frac{dP(1-x)}{dx}=-1$$

## Request

@usainlightning ask for $p'(1-x)$, here is the answer
$$p'(x)=1\implies p'(1-x)=1=\frac{dP(1-x)}{d(1-x)}$$

Comment: Sorry the title is confusing i'm looking for p'(1-x) not [p(1-x)]'